# Delete substring in dictionary keys to generate new keys

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary that looks like this:

```py
name_score_mapping = {
    'images/distorted/png/31LVTDXBL7AOT2QXJYOJ7PTCYKULRH_00_l.png': 1.2, 
    'images/distorted/png/3NVC2EB65QZGAZCURNCDJZSS1ILY3F_00_l.png': 1.6, 
    'images/distorted/png/3KWTYT08703ZOFSZMRBG4OOG64KL5M_00_l.png': 3.0
}
```

And the desired output should look like this:

```py
new_dict = {
    '31LVTDXBL7AOT2QXJYOJ7PTCYKULRH_00_l': 1.2, 
    '3NVC2EB65QZGAZCURNCDJZSS1ILY3F_00_l': 1.6, 
    '3KWTYT08703ZOFSZMRBG4OOG64KL5M_00_l': 3.0
}
```

Here is what I tried: I got rid of the pathnames `images/distorted/png/` and the ending `.png`. I managed to do this with `sub()` regular expression method:

```py
allslice = [
    r'\bimages/distorted/png/\b',
    r'\bimages/original/png/\b',
    r'\b.png\b'
]

get_values = list(name_score_mapping.values())
oldkeys = list(name_score_mapping.keys())
newkeys = [re.sub('|'.join(allslice), '', str(oldkeys)) for s in oldkeys]
```

Output:

```
newkeys = ["['31LVTDXBL7AOT2QXJYOJ7PTCYKULRH_00_l', '3NVC2EB65QZGAZCURNCDJZSS1ILY3F_00_l',3KWTYT08703ZOFSZMRBG4OOG64KL5M_00_l']"]
```

I removed the outer list. Then I would like to generate a new dictionary using `newkeys` as keys and `name_score_mapping` values. I tried with the `zip()` method like this:

```
newkeys = newkeys[0]

new_dict = {k: v for k, v in zip(newkeys, get_values)}
```

Output:

```
new_dict = {'[': 1.2, "'": 3.0, '3': 1.6}
```

I don't understand why the strings in the keys are not recognized but get split up. Also, the values are not in order.

Answer (score 3):

Since those strings represent filenames, I would use `os.path` to parse the parts that you want. Specifically `os.path.basename` will remove the folder and retrive just the filename (e.g. `'3NVC2EB65QZGAZCURNCDJZSS1ILY3F_00_l.png'`) then `os.path.splitext` will split off the filename from the extention.

```
>>> import os
>>> {os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(k))[0]: v for k,v in name_score_mapping.items()}
{'31LVTDXBL7AOT2QXJYOJ7PTCYKULRH_00_l': 1.2,
 '3NVC2EB65QZGAZCURNCDJZSS1ILY3F_00_l': 1.6,
 '3KWTYT08703ZOFSZMRBG4OOG64KL5M_00_l': 3.0}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple way to achieve that using just `str.split()` and comprehensions:

```py
>>> d = {
...     'images/distorted/png/31LVTDXBL7AOT2QXJYOJ7PTCYKULRH_00_l.png': 1.2, 
...     'images/distorted/png/3NVC2EB65QZGAZCURNCDJZSS1ILY3F_00_l.png': 1.6, 
...     'images/distorted/png/3KWTYT08703ZOFSZMRBG4OOG64KL5M_00_l.png': 3.0
... }
>>> 
>>> {k.split('/')[-1].split('.')[0]: v for k, v in d.items()}
```

Resulting in:

```py
{
   '31LVTDXBL7AOT2QXJYOJ7PTCYKULRH_00_l': 1.2, 
   '3NVC2EB65QZGAZCURNCDJZSS1ILY3F_00_l': 1.6, 
   '3KWTYT08703ZOFSZMRBG4OOG64KL5M_00_l': 3.0
}
```

Putting it all together, your code would look like:

```py
name_score_mapping = {
    'images/distorted/png/31LVTDXBL7AOT2QXJYOJ7PTCYKULRH_00_l.png': 1.2, 
    'images/distorted/png/3NVC2EB65QZGAZCURNCDJZSS1ILY3F_00_l.png': 1.6, 
    'images/distorted/png/3KWTYT08703ZOFSZMRBG4OOG64KL5M_00_l.png': 3.0
}

new_dict = {
    k.split('/')[-1].split('.')[0]: v
    for k, v in name_score_mapping.items()
}
```

And here is an extra option using `pathlib.Path()`:

```py
from pathlib import Path

name_score_mapping = {
    'images/distorted/png/31LVTDXBL7AOT2QXJYOJ7PTCYKULRH_00_l.png': 1.2, 
    'images/distorted/png/3NVC2EB65QZGAZCURNCDJZSS1ILY3F_00_l.png': 1.6, 
    'images/distorted/png/3KWTYT08703ZOFSZMRBG4OOG64KL5M_00_l.png': 3.0
}

new_dict = {
    Path(k).stem: v
    for k, v in name_score_mapping.items()
}
```

Comment: Thank you! The output looks like desired however in my original dataset there were 600 key/value pairs and now there are only 598. I will look into this!

Comment: You probably have a duplicate file name entry somewhere, yielding to a duplicate key and resulting in the last value seen as the one ending in the dictionary.